# exclude a file name in FOR LOOP

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I had few files with names as cp1_2015_09_10.txt  cp3_2015_09_11.txt kmps_2014_08_03.txt and cpms_2015_07_10.txt ksms_2015_10_07.txt in a folder of D drive subdirectory of check folder. i wanted to remove the file name from the for loop with like _2015_10_07 for today's date

```
setlocal
SET /A MAXJ=1
SET /A J=1

set   year=%date:~10,4% 

set year=%year: =%
echo %year%

set  month=%date:~7,2%
set month=%month: =%

set  day=%date:~4,2%
set day=%day: =%

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (DIR /S /B D:\check\*.txt| find /v "_%year%_%month%_%day%")  DO ( 

    SET XCOUNT_!J!=%%~i
SET MAXJ=!J!
    SET /A J+=1)
SET XCOUNT

SET /A J-=1

@echo COUNT OF FILES IS : %J%
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I wanted to remove the file name from the for loop

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (DIR /S /B D:\check\*.txt| find /v "_%year%_%month%_%day%")  DO (
```

Your `for` syntax is incorrect in two ways:

1. You are using `usebackq`

   - That means the command argument to `for` **must** be delimited with back quotes <kbd>`</kbd>
2. You are not escaping the pipe symbol.

   - Replace the pipe `|` symbol with `^|`

Corrected `for` command:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`DIR /S /B D:\check\*.txt ^| find /v "_%year%_%month%_%day%"`)  DO (
```

There may also be other errors in your batch file ...

---

#### Syntax

> FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ('command_to_process') DO command
>
> Key
>
> options:
>
> usebackq     Use the alternate quoting style:
>
> - Use double quotes for long file names in "filenameset".
> - Use single quotes for 'Text string to process'
> - Use back quotes for `command_to_process`

Source [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

---

#### Escape Character

`^`  Escape character.

Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be treated as ordinary text.

When piping or redirecting any of these characters `&`, `\`, `<`, `>`, `^` or `|` you should prefix them with the escape character.

For example `^\`  `^&`  `^|`  `^>`  `^<`  `^^`

Source [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.